# TypeError: register.route(...).use is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using `express.Router()` whenever i try `use` method it gives the following error
`TypeError: register.route(...).use is not a function`

**Code**
/server/routes

```
const express = require('express');
const register = express.Router();
const account = require("../controller/AccountController");
const Middleware = require("../utils/middlewares");


register.route('/')
    .post(Middleware.checkUser)
    .post(account.user_register)


register.route('/verify/:token')
    .get(Middleware.verifyEmail)

register.route('/resend/:email')    
    .use(Middleware.sendVerification)


module.exports = register;
```

Server.js

```
server.use('/register', register);
```

When i use a method like `get` there is no error. But i don't want to use any method since the middleware just sends an email

Comment: Instead of register.route try register.get register.post etc

Comment: But i dont want to use any method, the middleware just sends an email. Nothing more..  it wont make sense if i use get or post if it doesn't return data or add new data

Comment: All HTTP requests require a method to be specified.

Comment: *But i don't want to use any method since the middleware just sends an email* - a middleware applies to *all* methods. If a middleware doesn't make sense for most of them (in this case it doesn't) then it doesn't make sense to specify it for all methods. I can hardly imagine that there are valid reasons to allow `/resend/` to be requested with e.g PATCH. I would expect that it is normally requested with GET. Then `.get` should be used. It seems like you're confusing middlewares with route handlers. verifyEmail and sendVerification names sound like route handlers, not middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.route), route `all` method is intended for route-specific middleware, it could be:

```
register.route('/resend/:email')    
    .all(Middleware.sendVerification)
```

If the route is expected to be requested with GET only and may not make sense for other verbs, it should be narrowed down to supported verbs:

```
register.route('/resend/:email')    
    .get(Middleware.sendVerification)
```

In this case `sendVerification` seems to be route handler and not a middleware. It's suitable to specify it only for `get` if `/resend/` is expected to be requested with GET.